Let's get critical: Jun 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Cryptography Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Dose the Skip bug still exist? Where if you skip a question for now you can't answer it later?

@CodesInChaos I didn't try it, but that seems to be a common "feature" of all the review queues.

@CodesInChaos (I know June 25 is a long time ago, but…) Personally, I think of that button as a “I'm not sure what to make of individual review, so before I decide something wrong, let me simply skip this” option. I might be wrong, but that interpretation hasn't failed me yet. ;)

Final Results

Injecting salt into PyCrypto KDF - useful?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)  
Is Base64(SHA1(GUID)) still unique like the original GUID?
Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 0)  
AES plaintext is smaller than 128 bits - how to expand?
Net Score: 7 (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)  
Attacking AES/CCM with random IV
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)  
Increased CRC collision probability when adding bits to input message
Net Score: 7 (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)  
How does OAEP improve the security of RSA?
Net Score: 8 (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)  
Polynomial multiplication and division in2^128
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)  
How does the birthday attack work in AUTH and UF-CMA games?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)  
Proper Way to Encrypt Data with Two Keys?
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)  
Why is SRP not widely used?
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)  


Mean: 3.4, stddev: 3.1693, for any wondering
